# How can I get rid of the scientific number formatting of Google Sheets via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, text-formatting

Is there a way to obtain a cell value from Google Sheets which contains a phone number as text in Google Apps Script.

I mean. My sheet contains a list of employees with names and phone numbers like:

```
Employee  phone          mail
Emp1.     5544477991     emp1@mail.com
Emp1.     1234567988     emp2@mail.Com
...       .......        ......
```

An on the script I wrote:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
R=sheet.getRange("A1:D2").getValues();
for (var f = 0 ; f<3 ; f++) {
    Logger.log(R[0][f])
}
```

For 5544477991 I get 5.54447799E9.

How can I get rid of the scientific number formatting of Google Sheets via Google Apps Script?

Comment: Use `toString()` function. For an instance, `R[0][f].toString();`

Comment: When entered manually you can use a ' before the numbers... example '212456787,  it will be invisible but implicitly make the number become a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user1989 using toString() works perfectly.